# How to programmatically slice an image in 4 , 9 , 16 and 25 slices

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

i need a little help to slice a picture programatically in 4 , 9 ,16 and 25 slices

I would appreciate any help or idea . Thanks

Comment: `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` will help you to slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple app for this purpose. You can download from here:

https://github.com/bpolat/Image-Slicer

The code you require is:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getImagesFromImage:(UIImage *)image withRow:(NSInteger)rows   withColumn:   (NSInteger)columns
 {
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
CGFloat xPos = 0.0, yPos = 0.0;
CGFloat width = imageSize.width/rows;
CGFloat height = imageSize.height/columns;
for (int y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
    xPos = 0.0;
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        CGImageRef cImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage],  rect);

        UIImage *dImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cImage];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x*width, y*height, width, height)];
        [imageView setImage:dImage];
        [imageView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        [images addObject:dImage];
        xPos += width;
    }
    yPos += height;
}
return images;
  }
```

Usage:

```
[self getImagesFromImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] withRow:4 withColumn:4];
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(size.width / 4, size.height / 4 , 
(size.width / 2), (size.height / 2));
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

And check out these links :
[Cropping and resizing image](http://www.samwirch.com/blog/cropping-and-resizing-images-camera-ios-and-objective-c)
[CGImage Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/index.html)