# How to slice an image with even height and width 4X4 = 16 Pieces?

Tags: ios, image, uiimage, cocos2d-x

I am doing on sliding puzzle game i need to help for how to slice image and make the more sprite images this images are arranging to descending order the player will arrange to correct position.

Know idea how to slice the image in cocos2d-x 3.2 anybody please help to me solve this.

Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice sprite in cocos2d-x using `setTextureRect()`. For example, here's the code for the 16 segments, you can change it for your number:

```
Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
vector<Sprite*> vecSprites;
for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
{
    Sprite* segment = Sprite::create("example.png");
    float segmentWidth = segment->getBoundingBox().size.width / 4;
    float segmentHeight = segment->getBoundingBox().size.height / 4;
    float originX = (i % 4) * segmentWidth;
    float originY = ((int)i/4) * segmentHeight;
    segment->setTextureRect(Rect(originX, originY, segmentWidth, segmentHeight));
    vecSprites.push_back(segment);
}
```

Display segments of the sprite on the screen in the reverse order:

```
for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
{
    vecSprites[i]->setPosition((i%4) * visibleSize.width / 4, (((int)i/4) + 1) * visibleSize.height / 4);
    vecSprites[i]->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ANCHOR_TOP_LEFT);
    this->addChild(vecSprites[i]);
}
```

Result:
[image]
Of course, you can display them in random order. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for this code is working.

Comment: Better than thank is accept answer)

Comment: Yes this is better then one more question, How to touch move this segments?

Comment: Just google it, [for example](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/move-a-sprite-by-touching-and-dragging-it/17892)

Comment: i will try more time but segment sprite move the last tag only.. i need to touch any of segment and move to freedom. please    dude..

Comment: I can't give you answer in comment. It can require more than 500 characters. Try to create the new question, give your code example, and everyone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether it works in cocos2d or not, but its perfect solution in iOS.
Please follow the given link:
[How to programmatically slice an image in 4 , 9 , 16 and 25 slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106391/xcode-slice-an-image-in-4-9-16-and-25-slices)

You can also download application from Github:
https://github.com/bpolat/Image-Slicer

Comment: Thanks for that tip,